# .NET Framework on Android

Tags: c#, .net, android, mobile, cross-compiling

Is anyone aware of any projects out there to port a version of the .NET framework to the Android platform, kind of like [Mono.Touch](http://monotouch.net/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that you can build Mono for the Android with little more than the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.5_r1/index.html). More info at http://www.koushikdutta.com/search/label/Mono; source code, instructions, etc are [on Github](http://github.com/koush/androidmono).

Answer (score 4):

I know the mono team is working on an android port. However Miguel hasn't posted any recent news about it from what I can tell.

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Jan-05-1.html

and

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Feb-16.html

Answer (score 2):

MonoDroid (Mono for Android) is ready to enter a public beta cycle now. Launch is scheduled to summer 2010.

For details see:

- http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/May-21.html
- http://www.go-mono.com/monodroid/

Answer (score 1):

Miguel de Icaza's announced on his [blog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-17.html) on the 17th of Feb 2010 that they are starting work on mono for android which will be called MonoDroid.

This will be similar to MonoTouch on the iphone but for android instead.